# backward one step in telegram bot (using ReplyKeyboardMarkup)

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm new in telegram-Bot programming.

We have a menu in a bot (using ReplyKeyboardMarkup)
& menu1 has submenu1,submenu2,submenu3
& submenu1 has submenu1-1 & submneu1-2

now i'm in submneu1-2 how can backward one step?
(From submneu1-2 -> submenu1  )

Answer (score 0):

there is no such a method in telegram bot API in order to do it. its more like designing problem. but anyway. the solution is keeping session for users. you have to save the user current session. for example if user sent the submenu1 and then submenu1-1, you should take him/her back to submenu1 if he/she press the back button.

but there is an alternative way. you can use the unique back buttons. this way you can simply manage the requests. for example you can have BackToMain and BackToFirstMenu instead simple back button.

Comment: can u get a sample?